# Join one-to-many relation to exclude some rows based on condition

Tags: sql, join

I have one-to-many relationship between `customer` and `Customer Contract` table

Customer table

```
id|name
 1|Jared  
 2|Taylor
```

Customer Contract table

```
id|CustomerID|StatusID
 1|1         |2
 2|2         |1
 3|1         |2
 4|1         |3
```

Now I want to create view to retrieve only the customer who's not having
a last status of 2 in `customer contract`

Expected result

```
id|CustomerID
 1|2
```

CustomerID 2 is retrieved because his last status is not equal to 2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `not exists`:

```
select c.*
from customers c
where not exists (select 1
                  from customercontracts cc
                  where cc.customerid = c.id and cc.statusid = 2
                 );
```

Comment: Can't I achieve the same using join?

Comment: @r_via . . . Yes, but this is almost a direct translation of what you are asking for into SQL.

Comment: I updated my question. Also isn't join is better in performance?

Comment: @r_via . . . No.

Answer (score 0):

> I want to create view to retrieve only the customer who's not having a last status of 2 in customer contract

You can use a correlated subquery to retrieve the last status, and use that for filtering:

```
create view customer_view as
select c.*
from customer c
where (
    select statusid 
    from customercontracts cc 
    where cc.customerid = c.customerid 
    order by id desc 
    limit 1
) <> 2
```

Comment: Is correlated subquery good in performance? I have a very large table and I'd like to use the best approach

Comment: For performance, you want an index on `customercontract(customerid, id, statusid)`.

Comment: I have it already , Now I'm doing a research on it and I found that using left outer join is better in performance

Comment: @r_via: that is not true in general. With the correct index in place, a correlated subquery is often more efficient.